# Need to compare one Pandas (Python) dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, analysis

So I've pulled data from an sql server, and inputted into a dataframe. All the data is of discrete form, and increases in a 0.1 step in one direction (0.0, 0.1, 0.2... 9.8, 9.9, 10.0), with multiple power values for each step (e.g. 1000, 1412, 134.5, 657.1 at 0.1), (14.5, 948.1, 343.8 at 5.5) - hopefully you see what I'm trying to say.

I've managed to group the data into these individual steps using the following, and have then taken the mean and standard deviation for each group.

`group = df.groupby('step').power.mean()
group2 = df.groupby('step').power.std().fillna(0)`

This results in two data frames (group and group2) which have the mean and standard deviation for each of the 0.1 steps. It's then easy to create an upper and lower limit for each step using the following:

`upperlimit = group + 3*group2
lowerlimit = group - 3*group2
lowerlimit[lowerlimit<0] = 0`

Now comes the bit I'm confused about! I need to go back into the original dataframe and remove rows/instances where the power value is outside these calculated limits (note there is a different upper and lower limit for each 0.1 step).

Here's 50 lines of the sample data:

```
Index    Power              Step
0        106.0              5.0
1        200.4              5.5
2        201.4              5.6
3        226.9              5.6
4        206.8              5.6
5        177.5              5.3
6        124.0              4.9
7        121.0              4.8
8         93.9              4.7
9        135.6              5.0
10       211.1              5.6
11       265.2              6.0
12       281.4              6.2
13       417.9              6.9
14       546.0              7.4
15       619.9              7.9
16       404.4              7.1
17       241.4              5.8
18        44.3              3.9
19        72.1              4.6
20        21.1              3.3
21         6.3              2.3
22         0.0              0.8
23         0.0              0.9
24         0.0              3.2
25         0.0              4.6
26        33.3              4.2
27        97.7              4.7
28        91.0              4.7
29       105.6              4.8
30        97.4              4.6
31       126.7              5.0
32       134.3              5.0
33       133.4              5.1
34       301.8              6.3
35       298.5              6.3
36       312.1              6.5
37       505.3              7.5
38       491.8              7.3
39       404.6              6.8
40       324.3              6.6
41       347.2              6.7
42       365.3              6.8
43       279.7              6.3
44       351.4              6.8
45       350.1              6.7
46       573.5              7.9
47       490.1              7.5
48       520.4              7.6
49       548.2              7.9
```

Comment: Post your data and samples of your data frames. Also google the Pandas.DataFrame.Lookup() function.

Comment: Post `group` and `group2` You need to give as much info as is both helpful and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put you goal another way, you want to perform some manipulations on grouped data, and then project the results of those manipulations back to the ungrouped rows so you can use them for filtering those rows.  One way to do this is with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

> The transform method returns an object that is indexed the same (same size) as the one being grouped. Thus, the passed transform function should return a result that is the same size as the group chunk.

You can then create the new rows directly:

```
df['upper'] = df.groupby('step').power.transform(lambda p: p.mean() + 3*p.std().fillna(0))
df['lower'] = df.groupby('step').power.transform(lambda p: p.mean() - 3*p.std().fillna(0))
df.loc[df['lower'] < 0, 'lower'] = 0
```

And sort accordingly:

```
df = df[(df.power <= df.upper) & (df.power >= df.lower())]
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much. 

However, to add one little element of complexity - when there is a unique value of 'step', this method removes that row of the dataframe entirely (mathematically makes sense). Is it possible to keep that unique row?

For example, the value of 5.3 in 'step' (power = 177.5, index = 5) occurs only once, of course rendering a standard deviation of zero, and so creating the upper and lower bounds as exactly equal to the power value of 177.5. I want to keep this point however for analysis purposes, as it is the unique value of 'step'. Thanks

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove the data you want to exclude from the filter prior to filtering, and then add it back in once the filtering is done.